# C# - StreamResourceInfo from absolute uri path

Tags: c#, path, uri, absolute

If I add a jpg file to my solution in VS and do it like this:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri("pix500.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

It works correctly, but when I try to do it with an absolute path like this:

```
            Uri uri = new Uri(@"c:\pix500.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
```

It gives me the following exception on the second line:

Additional information: Unsupported URI syntax. Method expects a relative URI or a pack://application:,,,/ form of absolute URI.

Any insight on why it's not working?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.   Resources are relative paths embedded in your application.  Are you trying to read an arbitrary file on disk?

Comment: Hint: Look at `System.IO`, but don't assume that the user has a `C:` drive.

Comment: A URI is not the same as a file path even when it is absolute

Comment: As SLaks correctly said.  My mistake was ignoring the fact that resources will be embedded in my application.  I changed StreamResourceInfo for a FileStream and it worked correctly.